# Xcode- Library not found for - IGoogleUtilities

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I am new to Apple and Xcode, I make an application in unity3d and I try to implement AdMob. When I Run for test in xCode I have the error: Library not found for- IGoogleUtilities.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYOlg.jpg

Also when I select "Simulator SDK" from Build Settings/Player Settings/Other Settings the build Button is interactable

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it'il help someone;
"When using Unity 5.6 and above, an xcworkspace is generated that includes the required dependency libraries. Use the generated xcworkspace instead of the standard Xcode project."

Answer (score 0):

Select device SDK from Unity editor.

inside Xcode, You should [download](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/download) and add GoogleMobileAds.framework then rebuild.

Let me know if it helps.